# I have a problem with replacing N74LS05N in an old pcb

Tags: integrated-circuit

As inputs are connected in parallel with control inputs to Com via 10kohm resistors (to tie them to 0V when control input is floating, in absence of input (input in my case 4.5V=HI or isolated by diode so floating =LOW) LOW signal is expected for inverting into 5V output. What I have is LOW output.

When I measured input voltage I found it is 1.1V. Surprised (I thought 0V this should be) I checked data sheet for similar IC: Texas Instruments SN74S05. Internal circuit suggests that a Zener diode enables Vcc to close circuit via external (in my case 10kohm) resistor and this is where the 1.1V is created.

This 1.1V although below expected 2V for High input inverts output to 0V. 
Old IC's (25 years old) which I still have fitted (but sadly not spare), do show about 1V on input when control input is LOW, but do not produce output HI. Can anyone suggest how to overcome this problem? Thanks.

[**SN74LS05N data sheet here**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls05.pdf)

Comment: Got a schematic?

Comment: No offence, but this is hard to read. Could you use some formatting, paragraphs, perhaps add a circuit diagram or a photo if those are relevant?

Comment: Circuit and/or MUCH clearer and better formatted question needed. 74S and 74LS are different enough that you should use the correct data sheet. LS Shhottky inputs float high if not pulled down BUT this should not be relied on for design purposes.

Comment: Was the original part a 74C05 or 74HC05?  Those parts (or anything with a "C" in the middle) are CMOS, and have very high input impedance.  A CMOS part will work fine with a 10K pull-down, while a bipolar part (74LS, 74S, or plain 74) will not.

Answer (score 3):

**Short:** A 10k pulldown resistor is too high for an LSTTL inverter - input current flowing in the resistor is causing Vin to rise to an "illegal" state. is . A maximum resistor of around 1K is probably in order.

**Detail:**

Look at the LS05 functional diagram on page 3 of the
[SN74LS05N data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls05.pdf) datasheet.

[image]

Your Vin is above the maximum allowed Vinmax of 0.8V.
Vinlow_max is 0.8V and Vin_hi_min is 2V so at 1.1V your input is in an "illegal" or undefined state.

Note that the inverter's input transistor has a pullup resistor and the base is connected to the input via a Schottky diode so Vin will be somewhat lower than the transistor base voltage.

If you see Vin = 1.1V then transistor base is at say 1.4V and the two transistors in the inverter are turned on.

Iinlow max is 0.4 mA.
This means that to pull the input low you need to be able to sink 0.4 mA into the pulldown worst case. With 10K pulldown resistors the voltage at the input COULD be as much as V = IR = 0.4 mA x 10k = 4V.  It will never reach this voltage because as Vin rises the current decreases until a steady (and illegal) state is reached.

Comment: Thank you Russell, tried 7kohm and it works. Don't want to go below because in the case of my pcb, input to inverter is in parallel with 5 other inverters and all can simultaneously come from single output of a CD4017BE causing overload. Regards

Comment: @Richard If you have 5 inverter inputs in parallel then each can source 0.4 mA worst case = 2 mA. So to stay under 0.8V you need < = R = V/I = 0.8V/2 mA = 400 Ohms. You are extremely lucky that it works with 7K. Why are you mixing CMOS and LS TTL? Can you change the LS05 to a CMOS part. Why 5 in parallel. Why no circuit shown. Why did you not mention the 5 in parallel before. What else may affect operation that you have not mentioned?

Comment: Hello Russell, I'm just repairing an old pcb. Someone over 20 years ago designed and made this one off pcb. Some functions didn't work for years and I realised that people before me tried to replace original N74LS05N IC's without success (I found many of these, different brands hence my conclusion). I can't just replace the 10k resistors (array type) as copper art rather weak. I had to solder 22k resistors in parallel to each 10k. Doesn't look great but pcb works.

Comment: Russell, forgot to mention: pcb is 5V only. Not possible or economical to redesign. The 0V pindown resistance is at 5V at CD4017BE Hi output so at 7k 0.71mA each of 5 so 3.6mA total. I think that's load enough for it. Other original N74LS05N's work well for many years. New IC's don't behave same way. Have no spares. Thanks again for your interest.